# Exception is itself null?

Tags: java, android, exception, null

I am getting exception as null.
I don't understand why it is happening and how can i resolve it. 
please guide. 
[image]

Edit:
i tried to call it with inner class it is throwing null exception .
and with public class defined outside the  class it is working fine.

Note : The class is a asyncTask from which i am calling it.

Comment: Have you tried to print out your exception? It could be a debug error where it's not showing the correct value.

Comment: I have never seen that happen... I believe it is a bug in your IDE.

Comment: Try to catch the subtype of Exception you need for every case, just 1 catch with Exception is not very useful.

Comment: I had the same problem once and posted a question on SO, check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586563/ioexception-e-is-null

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the fact that you might've caught a `NullPointerException`? Try doing the following in your catch clause:

```
Log.d("TAG", "ex.toString() => " + ex.toString());
```

This phenomenon is called [a "naked null"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8899123/860212) (see the comments for more information).